# Can someone see Google passwords if he gets access to my PC?

Tags: google-chrome, security, passwords

If someone gets access to files in folders like `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\`, can he somehow see my passwords?

Or replace the login data on the PC?

Or does Google Chrome not save the login info on the PC?

Comment: You choosed it whether saves or not.

Answer (score 6):

Passwords are stored encrypted. That doesn't mean they can't have access to your account otherwise.

If you store passwords within google chrome, and they copy your profile, they do copy your password database too. If they then open google chrome with your profile, they can simply navigate to the various sites and login without even entering a password. If they want, they can then go to settings and change your password.

If you fear for this, then you may want to consider using a service such as LastPass. It stores your passwords in the cloud rather than locally, meaning that even with your profile, they cannot get in. Plugins are not stored in your profile and LastPass will require a login after installing it again, even if its data is copied, and you previously had the password cached.

But if someone has access to your pc and they can run chrome, they can simply access your sites through there anyway.

Comment: They can open my google chrome with my account only if i leave my PC with my logged account? Or maybe they can open Chrome with my account on other PC if they have full access to my files? Maybe they can copy some files for opening Chrome at other PC as currently logged?

Comment: If they have full access to your files they can copy your profile and get access to the passwords on a different pc.

Comment: How can they do this? What files need to be copied for this?

Comment: The entire profile located in %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome. If you copy this folder to a new computer and you launch Chrome, you continue where you left off on the other computer with most settings in tact.

Comment: No, i tried copy AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\- its now working.

Answer (score 0):

**Technically Yes**. 
By default google chrome save you passwords in this location of a computer
***C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default*** and it's the **Login Data** file. 
so if he take the data file and replace this file in his pc , he can sync the password and view the passwords. Thanks

Comment: No, replace this file is not enough. I've tried it just now.